# What is the proper way to open a stream in Java

Tags: java, java-io

I will be performing a lecture on Java for students of Physics, and I would like to know how to properly open a file.

In many my proffesional apps I did somethings like that:

```
  BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file")));
  try{
    ....
  }finally {
     bufferedWriter.close();
  }
```

which is IMHO ok, i.e. reader will allways be closed.

When I was putting that in example for my students I was wondering what will happen if constructor of `InputStreamReader` will throw an exception --- FileInputStream will be open, but it will not be closed by my code (since these objects are created outside try-finally block.

So is this right idiom, and if so then why? If it is not right idiom to open a stream please point me the right one!

**Edit**: I'm looking for idiom that is both correct and *very easy to write and understand*,  physics students are beginners in programming.

**Edit**: Silly me I copied wrong example --- if instead of Readers I use Writers it get's more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reading with input streams

Prior to Java 7 this is how you'd do it

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
     in = new FileInputStream("simple.csv");
     BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
} finally {
  if (in != null) {
     try {
         in.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {}
  }
}
```

For Java 7 you can use [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), something like

```
try (BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(...)) {}
```

---

**EDIT:** Why didn't I close `buf` above? Have a look at the source code for [`BufferedReader.close()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html)

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (in == null)
            return;
        in.close();
        in = null;
        cb = null;
    }
}
```

---

### Writing with output streams

**EDIT 2:** The same principle applies to *writers*. However if you're *really* interested in flushing a stream when the `IOException` occurs, then you must check both the `writer` and the `stream` for `null` and try tro close them respectively. That though, gives a lot of extra code. It could look something like this:

```
BufferedWriter buf = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream("file");
    buf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
} finally {
  if (buf != null) {
     try { buf.close(); } catch (IOException ex){}
  }
  if (out != null) {
     try { out.close(); } catch (IOException ex){}
  }
}
```

It's not very pretty. You could introduce a helper routine to close your streams or look into either Java 7 or [`Apache IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)

Comment: not quite...... (edit: never mind, you've fixed both my objections. I'd use `BufferedReader buf = null` just to be explicit)

Comment: This won't close the stream if `InputStreamReader` will throw an exception. You will also eventually cause another `NullPointerException`, because `buf` might be `null` here.

Comment: @RenéJeschke, thanks for noticing, I wasn't detailed oriented enough, I will fix it.

Comment: @jb. correct. Unless you want to reuse the buffered reader I see no point in doing it. You can of course, just in the same manner that `in` is being tested and closed.

Comment: AFAIK there is --- because before close buffers are flushed.

Comment: Yes! I pasted wrong example --- if you use writers instead of readers You migjt need to close all items in chain, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes that's right. However, do you *really* want to flush if an `IOException` occured?

Answer (score 0):

In this special case (nested constructors) the `FileInputStream` will stay open. You will have to do it like this (if you really need to assure the stream gets closed):

```
final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("");
try
{
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    // ...
}
finally
{
    fis.close();
}
```

Closing the `FileInputStream` should be sufficient.

Edit: The same logic can be applied to writers. If opening the `FileOutputStream` fails, it throws an exception which prevents the try/finally block from execution. And if any other writer constructor fails, the output stream still gets closed through the `final` clause.

Comment: Really I just need to find correct code example, and I'm not sure whether extra lines of code to check errors in FileInputStream constructor are worth the effort.

Comment: On the other hand, the only place where we would expect an exception is the constructor of `FileInputStream` because the file it wants to open might not be existent.