# Java httpserver cannot send large files

Tags: java, blob, httpserver

There are no error on the server side, but clients like Chrome and the application that needs the file can't download it. The server works with smaller files and it basically runs like this:

```java
package org.org.APIServer.api;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class APIServer {
    public static void startAPIServer() {
        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
            server.createContext("/api", new APIHandler());
            server.setExecutor(null);
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static class APIHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            byte[] responseBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("pack.zip"));
            t.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, responseBytes.length);
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(responseBytes);
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My test file is 1GB btw

Comment: `Files.readAllBytes` uhh, why not open the file as stream and write the output bit-by-bit? it has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959326/what-is-the-proper-way-to-open-a-stream-in-java), but im not sure your java version but that link should be sufficient example.

Comment: This is an extract from a larger codebase, it's used elsewhere and the file is also stored in RAM for faster loading

Comment: Well ... no matter what you think you are going to achieve by doing that, what you will actually do is create a lot of heap pressure, leading to extra GC load and possibly an OOME.  Which is better: marginally faster downloads or not crashing randomly?

Comment: again, the key is to read/write in chunks. putting everything in RAM is not advisable. unless you have a lot of it and only handle a couple of requests not thousands.

Comment: Also ... have you tried to identify how large a file that you *can* download?  That may help you (and us) to figure out what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: There is no reason to do it this way. It isn't 'marginally faster', it is actually *slower* , because you have the latency of reading the entire file before you've sent one byte of it. Use the standard Java copy loop and eliminate the whole problem.

Comment: The solution was to buffer the input and write small bits at a time, like Stephen C and Bagus Tesa mentioned, in the original codebase it was faster because it was read in once at application start, anyone it's resolved now.

Comment: @BagusTesa Could you post your buffering comment as an answer so that I can mark it as correct

Comment: @boomcreeper11   have you seen this "ramfileserver"  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RZIsA5_ap62B4RsUdyl8XODnHhxverAY/view?usp=sharing